# How to Speed up the execution of hive query to fetch data from external Cassandra in Wso2 BAM?

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

> I have connected wso2 bam with **external cassandra** . 
>       Successfully **inserted** data to **external cassandra**  .
>       Now i have written a hive query to fetch the data from this cassandra 
>       to  **postgresql**.Data   is  fetching and inserting successfully . But it
>       **taking more  time for execution of query** . Why this happening . How can 
>       I **reduce** the execution **time** . Is there any way to do this ?
>
> **please help**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using external cassandra 2.x?

If so try setting 'num_tokens' configuration in the cassandra.yaml to 1.  It configured to 256 in cassandra 2.x where as in older cassandra versions this configuration is commented out by default and hence it was taken as 1.

Thanks,
Harsha